# Same gcc compiler version giving different compilation results related to std namespace in different machines

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, namespaces

We have 3 linux CI machines with exact OS, cmake and compiler environments. OS is ubuntu 18.04 LTS, cmake 3.10.2 and GCC 7.5

There is a C++ code base with several .hpp files missing `std::` namespace prefix ex. for string, cout, endl etc.  There are also few .hpp files having wide namespace use i.e. `using namespace std` which is considered bad practice and we are removing these one by one. However the code compiles successfully on one of the CI machines but fails on other two. Even on the machines where compilation errors are seen, errors are about different hpp files.

What would cause the compiler to give different results on different CI machines when compilation environment is the same? Could it be parallel compilation or timing or the order the *.hpp files are parsed that using std namespace in some files affect the build outcome. The same machines give the same outcomes always as we tested with tens of clean builds from scratch.

Comment: "Could it be parallel compilation" ... possibly. The compiler will typically stop after the first few errors.

Comment: `using namespace std;` can cause weird errors, mistakenly add a `std::` when in fact a different function was called can cause also weird errors. It's a bit too late, but best is to avoid it from the beginning ;). Can you include a [mcve]?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the error messages verbatim.  Also be aware that the standard headers on different platforms/machines will have their own `#include` directives that can differ widely between machines.  That is, the set of headers pulled in transitively will differ.

Comment: Perhaps a bug in the build scripts? Is it reproducible, which machines are succesful and which are not?